# Exporting EXCEL files based on modified names of input files in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

For my MATLAB script, I load an EXCEL sheet.

```
filename='inp_x_arc.xlsx';
input=xlsread(filename);
```

Now I want to export my data to another EXCELsheet but instead of `inp_x_arc`, I want it to be `exp_x_arc`.

How can I automatically change the filename to replace `inp` to `exp` and keep the rest of the file name (`_x_arc.xlsx`).

so far I am entering everything manually as below:

```
xlswrite('exp_x_arc.xlsx',S)
```

Comment: `strfind` and some other string handling functions will work. Or even just literally just replacing the first 3 letters of filename. What have you tried

Comment: Dear Ander, currently I am just entering the string name manually. This is not efficient for me while I have about 200 files. I will update my post with what I have entered

Comment: `xlswrite(['exp_',filename(5:end)],S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest approach is to use regular expressions to anchor the substring `inp_` at the start of the string.

```
>>filename='inp_x_arc.xlsx';
>>str=regexprep(filename,'^inp_','exp_')

>>str =

    'exp_x_arc.xlsx'
```

---

As per the comments, using the raw character vector with `xlswrite` could cause Excel problems. In that scenario, it is safer to wrap the filename with [fullfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) before writing:

```
>>filename='inp_x_arc'; 
>>str=fullfile(regexprep(filename,'^inp_','exp_'));
```

It is generally recommended to try to avoid xlswrite and to use [writetable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) instead.

Comment: thank you very much. the string in this way can be produced nicely. However, when I export it to the Excel file, the .xlsx file becomes generated but it cannot be read by Excel and demonstrate this error: "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."
this error I do not get when I generate the EXCEL sheet as I shown in the firt post. This is also valid for what RadiaJava suggested. any suggestions?

Comment: here is the code now:    

  `%exp_filename=['exp_',filename(5:end)];  

  str=regexprep(filename,'^inp_','exp_')  

  xlswrite(str,S); `

Comment: Interesting, what MATLAB version are you using? Can you try using `writetable` instead of `xlswrite` ?

Comment: Can you open it if you run : `filename='inp_x_arc';
str=regexprep(filename,'^inp_','exp_');
xlswrite(str,S);` ?

Comment: @Hamed Does this code work: `str='exp_x_arc.xlsx';
xlswrite(str,S);` ? Maybe something wrong with passing a variable for some reason

Comment: @UnbearableLightness @RadioJava, none of these methods work. for all of them I have a corrupted EXCEL file. However, when I manually give the string `xlswrite('x_arc',S);`. I am using MATLAB 2015

Comment: Try wrapping it in `fullfile`: `filename='inp_x_arc';
str=fullfile(regexprep(filename,'^inp_','exp_'));
xlswrite(str,'abc');`

Comment: The error seems to be on the Excel side and not on MATLAB's. I am surprised **writetable** did not work...

Comment: well this works !!!
i am very surprised for some of the errors while logically I was not supposed to face them. 
`str=fullfile(regexprep(filename,'^inp_','exp_')); xlswrite(str,S); `
Thank you both very much @UnbearableLightness @Radiojava

Comment: @UnbearableLightness could you please add this to your main answer? I confirm the answer

Comment: @Hamed You are welcome, I updated my answer. Hopefully it can help future readers too.

Answer (score 1):

String manipulation:

```
exp_filename=['exp_',filename(5:end)];
```

OR

Using `strrep`:

```
exp_filename=strrep(filename,'inp_','exp_');
```

Note that using `strrep` will replace all occurences of `inp_`, if such exist, in the file name.

Comment: This works but it's probably worth noting that if the string contains the substring `inp_` at any other position in the string then that will be replaced as well.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness, true, which is why i showed the manual option too. Ill add that.

Comment: Thanks a lot RadioJava and Unbearable. Could you please check my comment on Unbearables comment?